# how to move char in a string from beginning to an end

Tags: c, pointers

As the title says, in my program I (after many procedures) get tokenized words.
Unfortunately due to reversing them they hold punctuation characters at the beginning of a word eg. ,moose

How to move that `,` from the beginning to the end -> moose,

Up to now I've tried(`ptr` is `char *`):

```
temp = strdup(ptr);
temp = &ptr[0];
ptr[0] = ptr[1];
ptr[strlen(ptr)-1] = temp;
free(temp);
```

But that gives me errors:

> assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

How to fix that?

Comment: Store the first char, loop through the char indices, setting each one to the next, set the last char to the first stored char.

Comment: The performance of that approach will degrade significantly for long strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
void swap_last(char *str)
{
  const size_t len = strlen(str);
  if(len > 1)
  {
    const char   first = str[0];
    memmove(str, str + 1, len - 1);
    str[len - 1] = first;
  }
}
```

Note that the above assumes `str` to be valid.

Comment: Thank You! I have a question, though. Why have You declared `len` and `first` with `const` at the beginning?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the comma should be its own token, so parsing it post-tokenizing is putting a second tokenizer after the first.

The best solution is to not *just* split on white space, but to recognize the comma as it's own token, so you can then test the presence of comma's as part of the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing your code and extrapolating for its lack of types, it's difficult to know the type of your `temp` variable -- because in some places you're using it like a `char *` and in others you're using it like a `char`.

I suspect the compiler error is on line `ptr[strlen(ptr)-1] = temp;` (because I suspect that `temp` is a `char *`), and the proper fix is: `ptr[strlen(ptr)-1] = *temp;`